# Can't get the data to fit in a single cell in a CSV file, what to do?

Tags: python, csv, dataset

This is the code I have tried and have been getting the following results. Have tried various approaches to this problem. The data into the CSV file seems to be spread over multiple columns and rows which is not ideal for my project. I have come to an understanding that there might be a memory of a single cell threshold that causing this problem.

```
for i in range(len(read1)):
  if read1[i] in opcodes:
    seq = seq + " " + read1[i]

print(seq)
csvname="/content/drive/MyDrive/sequence.csv"

#approach1

'''
dict1 = {"sequence":seq, "target":1}
'''

#apprach 2

'''
with open(csvname, 'w') as csvfile:
  csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
      
  # writing the fields 
  
      
  # writing the data rows 
  csvwriter.writerow(seq)
  break
''' 

'''
a_file = open(csvname, "w", newline="")
  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=[0]) 

#print(df)
# saving the dataframe 
df.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/sequence.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False) 
'''
#approach 3 -- very bad results
'''
csv_file = open(csvname, "w")
csv_file.write(seq)
'''


a_file.close()
```

Please not that I have commented various approaches to this problem and all the approaches seem to give a similar output

[It is spread over multiple cells and columns and rows. P.S: huge dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2zzh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, a CSV file cannot specify to Excel how it will be displayed. You would need to drag the column wider when it is loaded. If you want a single cell CSV, it would just be any data without a comma anywhere in it.

The following approach would give you a single cell, but it would still appear to spread over multiple cells. A list comprehension can be used to create `seq` from `read1` and `opcodes`. This is more efficient than repeatedly appending strings.

```
import csv

opcodes = ['cmp', 'add', 'dev', 'mov', 'retn', 'push', 'pop', 'lea']  # example data
read1 = ['cmp', 'test', 'add', 'sub', 'dev', 'mov', 'mul', 'retn', 'push']
seq = ' '.join(op for op in read1 if op in opcodes)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv.writer(f_output).writerow([seq])
```

Giving you a file containing:

```
cmp add dev mov retn push
```

This would initially be seen in Excel as:

[image: before]

But if you drag the column you would get:

[image: after]

If you want to automatically change how Excel displays the data, you would need to save your data in Excel format `.xlsx`. The column width could then be specified. This could be done using a library such as `openpyxl`.

Note: a second column could be added as follows:

```
csv.writer(f_output).writerow([seq, 'a second column'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped. Even after dragging it out for the first output, it didn't work (the data was spread). But, your code solved it all.